# Using maps or other data types (segment) when defining routes

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have this route using Akka Http:

```scala
...
private val entityActions = Map("action1" -> "action1", "action2" -> "action2")
...
val routes = path("entity" / entityActions) { action =>
          post {
            onComplete(someMethod()) {
              case Success(value) => ...                
              case Failure(e)     => ...
            }
          }
        }
...
```

So some app could hit these endpoints:

```
POST /entity/action1
POST /entity/action2
```

In this case every `key` and `value` in the Map are identical.
Is there any way to simplify this?

I tried using a `List` instead of `Map` but I didn't worked.

Comment: @ccheneson It means that the key is mapped to itself!

Comment: @M.G. I don't think that using map is a best practice for this, because probably `someMethod()` is based on what action you want to perform, right? what's the problem with using `pathPrefix("entity")` and then defining your actions inside separate `path` directives? I think that's much more clean than using the someMethod if it has a switch case!

Comment: Like this: ```pathPrefix("entity"){    path("action1") { whatever } ~ path("action2") { whatever else} }```

Answer (score 0):

You can reuse existing matchers to build own ones, like this:

```scala
  import akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatcher1
  import akka.http.scaladsl.server.PathMatchers.Segment

  def segmentOneOf(s: List[String]): PathMatcher1[String] = {
    Segment.tflatMap { tuple1 =>
      if (s.contains(tuple1._1))
        Some(tuple1)
      else
        None
    }
  }
```

It should work, but I have no way of running it at this moment.